# How to pass props in headerTitle inside options prop of a React Native Screen Component?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers#replacing-the-title-with-a-custom-component

In this link, there is an example code (copied below). Inside options prop, headerTitle is a function that accepts props as a parameter. Where do we pass that prop because we never actually call headerTitle. Is there some default prop which is passed and we are renaming it to props?

```
function LogoTitle() {
  return (
    <Image
      style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
      source={require('@expo/snack-static/react-native-logo.png')}
    />
  );
}

function StackScreen() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{ headerTitle: props => <LogoTitle {...props} /> }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can't pass the props. **React Navigation** is passing those props for you to use it if needed.

If you look [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headertitle) you will see what props are inside that object.